# Merge PDF based on size using Aspose

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, aspose, aspose.pdf

As I am new to Aspose, I need help in below case.
I want to merge multiple PDF into 1 PDF using Aspose, I can do it easily but the problem is, I want to limit the PDF size to 200MB.
That means, **If my merged PDF size is greater than 200MB, then I need to split the PDF into multiple PDF.** For Example, If my merged PDF is of 300MB, then first PDF should be of 200MB and second one PDF should be 100MB.

Main problem is, I am not able to find the size of the document in below code. I am using below code.

```
Document destinationPdfDocument = new Document();
                Document sourcePdfDocument = new Document();

            //Merge PDF one by one
            for (int i = 0; i < filesFromDirectory.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    destinationPdfDocument = new Document(filesFromDirectory[i].FullName);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Open second document
                    sourcePdfDocument = new Document(filesFromDirectory[i].FullName);

                    // Add pages of second document to the first
                    destinationPdfDocument.Pages.Add(sourcePdfDocument.Pages);


                    //** I need to check size of destinationPdfDocument over here to limit the size of resultant PDF**

                }
            }

            // Encrypt PDF
            destinationPdfDocument.Encrypt("userP", "ownerP", 0, CryptoAlgorithm.AESx128);

            string finalPdfPath = Path.Combine(destinationSourceDirectory, destinatedPdfPath);

            // Save concatenated output file
            destinationPdfDocument.Save(finalPdfPath);
```

**Other way of merging PDF based on size also be appreciated.**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no direct way to determine PDF file size before saving it physically. Therefore, we have already logged a feature request as **PDFNET-43073** in our issue tracking system and product team has been investigating the feasibility of this feature. As soon as we have some significant updates regarding availability of the feature, we will definitely inform you. Please spare us little time.

However, as a workaround, you may save document into a memory stream and place a check on the size of that memory stream, whether it exceeds from your desired PDF size or not. Please check following code snippet, where we have generated PDFs with desired size of 200MBs with aforementioned approach.

```
//Instantiate document objects
Document destinationPdfDocument = new Document();
Document sourcePdfDocument = new Document();

//Load source files which are to be merged
var filesFromDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(dataDir, "*.pdf");

for (int i = 0; i < filesFromDirectory.Count(); i++)
{    
 if (i == 0)
 {
 destinationPdfDocument = new Document(filesFromDirectory[i]);
 }
 else
 {
 // Open second document
 sourcePdfDocument = new Document(filesFromDirectory[i]);
 // Add pages of second document to the first
 destinationPdfDocument.Pages.Add(sourcePdfDocument.Pages);
 //** I need to check size of destinationPdfDocument over here to limit the size of resultant PDF**
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 destinationPdfDocument.Save(ms);
 long filesize = ms.Length;
 ms.Flush();
 // Compare the filesize in MBs
 if (i == filesFromDirectory.Count() - 1)
 {
  destinationPdfDocument.Save(dataDir + "PDFOutput_" + i + ".pdf");
 }
 else if ((filesize / (1024 * 1024)) < 200)
 continue;
 else
 {
  destinationPdfDocument.Save(dataDir + "PDFOutput_" + i.ToString() + ".pdf");
  destinationPdfDocument = new Document();
 }
 }
 }
```

I hope this will be helpful. Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.